# How to get OS RAM Usage using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, operating-system

How to get current memory usage using nodejs?

I have a backend application. When ram usage of the operating system is greater than 7GB, I want to decline user requests.

Answer (score 1):

The main tools you have built into nodejs without going to external programs are these:

```
process.memoryUsage()
process.memoryUsage.rss()
```

Probably you want the second one because resident set size is closest to the total OS RAM memory allocated to the process.